# Cannot use POST and PUT request at the same time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to POST and UPDATE a new user using django forms.

I have this function in my `views.py` beforehand and the POST request is working alright but then I realised I couldn't update:

```
def user_form(request, id=0):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm()
        else:
            user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(instance=user)
        return render(request, "user_register/user_form.html", {'form':form})
    else:
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/user/list')
```

It'll redirect me to the right page - but won't update when I check. I changed the code to this, and the update request worked fine but the problem now is it errors when I try to create a new user:

```
def user_form(request, id=0):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm()
        else:
            user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(instance=user)
        return render(request, "user_register/user_form.html", {'form':form})
    else:
        user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/user/list')
```

The error from the post request stems from the line after the `else:` and obviously the `instance=user` after `request.POST`, as that's what I've added from the original code

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your form doesn't validate. This would prevent it from saving. If you're using PUT and providing a subset of the fields in the form, that could be the issue why your form is not validating.

My suggestion is to improve your view method to re-render the form in case the form validation fails:

```py
def user_form(request, id=0):
    if request.method == "GET":
        if id == 0:
            form = UserForm()
        else:
            user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=id)
            form = UserForm(instance=user)
        return render(request, "user_register/user_form.html", {'form':form})
    else:
        user = NewUser.objects.get(pk=id)
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            render(request, "user_register/user_form.html", {'form': form})

        # Redirect ONLY if form validates
        return redirect('/user/list')
```

Note: PUT is not supported in traditional browser forms (e.g. the type `<form action="" method="post">`), only GET and POST.